# VB Parenthesis on conditions?

Tags: vb.net, conditional-statements, brackets

I have seen vb.net conditionals with and without parenthesis, `If (foo = bar) Then` or `If foo = bar Then`

So far I have been coding without them, as that seemed to be the convention in most examples and tutorials I've looked at (even on MSDN).
However I realised that parenthesis would be needed to set precedence in more complex expressions `If (foo = bar Or (bar < barMax And bar > barMin) Then`

So is it recommended to use them consistently or only when needed?

Comment: I'd use them consistently, but it's really a matter of personal preference or the coding standards your team has.  And technically those are parentheses :)

Comment: Cheers. In AE yes, but in BE it's mostly just brackets (and AE brackets become square brackets in BE) unless one is being exceedingly pedantic, you almost never hear "parenthesis" here :)

Comment: Have changed anyhoo, as I guess, to be reasonable, vb is written in AE ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is down to your own preference.

Personally I ***would not*** use them in a single expression like this:

`If foo = bar Then`

But I ***would*** use them in something like this (for clarity/readability)

`Dim boolValue = (foo = bar)`

***and*** this (to ensure that booleans are evaluated in the order I intended):

`If (foo = bar) Or (foo2 = bar2) Then`

Comment: The last example solves an unintuitive issue, thanks.